# How to store both integers and decimals in a column oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a column `(amount)` that has both integers and decimals. But the issue is the column always stores the values as integers.

```
CREATE TABLE payments(payment_id , Status , payment_date , account_id , currency, amount) AS
SELECT '72b30af0-323e-4931-8fcc-2c08ad8d0b19', 'completed', TO_DATE ('01/10/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'), 2291969088, 'GBP', CAST(10.00 AS NUMBER(20,18)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '1b5341c0-508c-450f-a139-bc898f112fed', 'completed', TO_DATE ('12/11/2014','DD/MM/YYYY'), 7851880663, 'USD', CAST(20 AS NUMBER) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '4c8eb68d-3085-4500-b735-371bb7e1ac97','submitted', TO_DATE ('03/07/2016','DD/MM/YYYY'), 5326844767, 'USD', CAST(3.000 AS NUMBER) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '33825ef2-d0da-4062-a435-b74a25a850ed','failed', TO_DATE ('19/01/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'), 3668657617, 'EUR', CAST(40 AS NUMBER) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '45c10898-d668-4ad1-9730-415254f6e085', 'completed', TO_DATE ('10/05/2017','DD/MM/YYYY'), 9040142052, 'GBP', CAST(30.000 AS NUMBER) FROM DUAL
```

I have tried using `Number` alone and `Number` with precision and scale but the result is the same even with the `Decimal` data type. Not sure what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Oracle does not store trailing decimal zeros. As the answers in the linked duplicates state, you need to either add another column to store the precision of your number or store the numbers as strings with the required precision; you cannot store a formatted number as a number.

Comment: Your problem is very special. Usually 10 and 10.0 and 10.00 and 10.000000 are the same number: ten. This is different though in some scientific context, where 10.00 means measured until two decimal places, so the real number may be 10.000 or 10.009 for instance. For all databases I know, a 10 and a 10.0000 are the same value. The precision is hence an additional information you wwould have to store in a separate column. (And you can use this information later to display the number with the desired precision.)

Answer (score 0):

The table will store the values in  a correct way.
Your select is the problem I believe.

```
select payment_id
       , Status 
       , payment_date 
       , account_id 
       , currency
       , to_char(amount, '99.999')
from payments;
```

I have used `to_char()` functionto format your column when selecting.
Please correct me if I am wrong.
[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=70bb377a7eadfdbc8ff38044a0047d2c)

Comment: That would convert all the numbers to decimal

Comment: @hyeri This answer is partly correct in that your problem is not a storage issue as `10` is the same value as `10.0` as is `10.000` and Oracle will always store them all as `10` and will never store the trailing zeros in a `NUMBER` data type (and the database may not even see the trailing zeros as the client may silently ignore them). Your issue is a display issue and you need to also maintain a column in the table to store the precision of each number and use that when you want to display the value.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on answer by @VBoka, providing more thorough example:

the root of your question is basic math.  Trailing zeros to the right of the decimal are insignificant.  10 = 10.0 = 10.000000.   You are confusing how the value is stored vs how it is displayed by default.

```
SQL> -- -------- create the tables
SQL> create table my_demo (my_id integer,
  2                        my_value number(5,2));

Table created.

SQL> -- -------- load tables
SQL> insert into my_demo values (1,10);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into my_demo values (2,10.0);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into my_demo values (3,010.00);

1 row created.

SQL> -- -------- Do the query
SQL> select my_id,
  2         my_value,
  3         to_char(my_value,'999.999') formatted_value
  4  from my_demo
  5  order by my_id
  6  ;

     MY_ID   MY_VALUE FORMATTE
---------- ---------- --------
         1         10   10.000
         2         10   10.000
         3         10   10.000

3 rows selected.
```

And why are you using "CAST(10.00 AS NUMBER"?   The 10.00 (without quotes) is already a number.  If you were to enclose it in single quotes ("CAST('10.00' AS NUMBER"), then it would be a string that needs to be treated with either CAST or TO_NUMBER.

== new demo for getting just integer values

```
SQL> -- -------- load tables
SQL> insert into my_demo values (1,10);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into my_demo values (2,10.0);

1 row created.

SQL> insert into my_demo values (3,010.10);

1 row created.

SQL> -- -------- Do the query
SQL> select my_id,
  2         my_value,
  3         to_char(my_value,'999.999') formatted_value
  4  from my_demo
  5  order by my_id
  6  ;

     MY_ID   MY_VALUE FORMATTE
---------- ---------- --------
         1         10   10.000
         2         10   10.000
         3       10.1   10.100

3 rows selected.

SQL> --
SQL> select my_id,
  2         my_value,
  3         to_char(my_value,'999.999') formatted_value
  4  from my_demo
  5  where my_value = trunc(my_value)
  6  order by my_id
  7  ;

     MY_ID   MY_VALUE FORMATTE
---------- ---------- --------
         1         10   10.000
         2         10   10.000

2 rows selected.
```

Comment: But that is the whole issue, I have to run a query 'What is the number of payments that have no decimal place?', this way I get 0 since all the values are stored or displayed as integers. In reality, it should show 2 as a result since 2 numbers have no decimal place. Also, I was using a cast to specify precision and scale for the Numbers

Comment: "have no decimal place" means nothing from a math perspective.  Do you mean "what is the number of payments that are integers"?  Is this homework?  I can't imagine it being a real business requirement.

Comment: @hyeri: I agree with EdStevens that the expression "payments that have no decimal place" doesn't seem to make sense. If person A got a dollar and person B got a dollar and zero cents, then both persons got the same money. You cannot say that person A got a "payment that has no decimal place" while person B got a "payment that has decimal places". This is just wrong.